# Converting Character in an array to an Integer

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I can't seem to figure out how to do this even though I've searched through documentation.

I'm trying to figure out how to convert a character at an index in an array to an integer.

For example, say I have a character array named "container", I can't figure out how to do:

```
var number:Integer = container[3]
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you mean the Swift type `Character` or `CChar`/`CString`?

Comment: I think you can call utf8 on the array and then find the corresponding index. I had this same problem when [converting a string to a double](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031621/swift-how-to-convert-string-to-double/24102778#24102778).

Comment: its type Array<Character>

Comment: Let's say the third element of the array is the character . What do you want `number` to end up as?

Answer (score 9):

Swift doesn't make it easy to convert between primitive and typed representations of things.  Here's an extension that should help in the meantime:

```
extension Character {
    func utf8Value() -> UInt8 {
        for s in String(self).utf8 {
            return s
        }
        return 0
    }

    func utf16Value() -> UInt16 {
        for s in String(self).utf16 {
            return s
        }
        return 0
    }

    func unicodeValue() -> UInt32 {
        for s in String(self).unicodeScalars {
            return s.value
        }
        return 0
    }
}
```

This allows you to get pretty close to what you want:

```
let container : Array<Character> = [ "a", "b", "c", "d" ]
/// can't call anything here, subscripting's also broken
let number = container[2]
number.unicodeValue() /// Prints "100"
```

For any engineers that come across this question, see rdar://17494834

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure that it is effective or not but at least it worked. I converted Character to String then to Int.

```
String(yourCharacterInArray).toInt()
```

Answer (score 4):

You may try this:

> ```
> var container = "$0123456789"
> var number:Int = Array(container.utf8).map { Int($0) }[3]
> ```

It's totally ugly, but it does the job. Also it is a bit computational expensive (O(n) each time one access a character in a string). Still this can be a trick to get back a way to build the CStrings:

> ```
> typealias CString = Array<CChar>
> func toCString(string: String) -> CString {
>     return Array(string.utf8).map { CChar($0) } + [0]
> }
> var cString = toCString("$ 0123456789")
> println("The 2nd character in cString has value \(cString[1])") // It outputs 32
> ```

or without implementing a function:

> ```
> var container = "$ 0123456789"
> var containerAsCString = Array(container.utf8).map { CChar($0) } + [0]
> println("The 2nd character in container has value \(containerAsCString[1])") // It outputs 32
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just convert the character to String, get the unicodeScalars for it and extract the .value on the scalar?

something like:

```
var chr: [Character] = ["C", "B", "A"]

for a in String(chr[1]).unicodeScalars {
    println(a.value)}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me worked something like:

```
"\(container[3])".toInt()
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not just for loop the array and convert everything to Int?

https://developer.apple.com/Library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/index.html