# Cannot convert Double to String

Tags: swift

"The Swift Programming Language" contains the following sample code:

```
let label = "The width is "
let width = 94
let widthLabel = label + String(width)
```

When I changed `width` implicitly to Double:

```
let width = 94.4
```

a compiler error is created for the line `let widthLabel = label + String(width)`:

> Cannot invoke '+' with an argument list of type (String, String)

While I can convert the `Double` var to `String` by calling `width.description`, I want to know:

1. Why `String(Integer)` works but `String(Double)` doesn't?
2. Is there any difference between calling `String(var)` and `var.description` on a numerical type (Integer, Float, Double, etc)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031621/swift-how-to-convert-string-to-double ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why you can't do that is because `String` doesn't have an initializer accepting a double or a float, whereas it implements initializers for all integer types (Int, Uint, Int32, etc.).

So @derdida's solution is the right way to do it.

I discourage using the `description` property. It is **not** meant to convert a double to a string, but to provide a human readable textual representation of a double. So, whereas today's representation coincides with the conversion:

```
let width = 94.5
println(width) // Prints "94.5"
```

tomorrow it can be changed to something different, such as:

```
ninety four point five
```

That's still human readable, but it's not exactly a conversion of double to string.

This rule is valid for all types (structs, classes, etc.) implementing the `Printable` protocol: the `description` property should be used to **describe**, not to **convert**.

**Addendum**

Besides using string interpolation, we can also use the old c-like string formatting:

```
let pi = 3.1415
let piString = String(format: "%0.2f", arguments:[pi])

let message = "Pi is " + String(format: "%0.2f", arguments:[pi])
println(message)
```

Comment: You are faster than me :)

Comment: So to convert a Double/Float to String it would be like: `let strVal="\(doubbleVal)"`? This seems quite idiosyncratic.

Comment: You can also use c-like string formatting - see updated answer

Answer (score 1):

I would use this when you like to create a string value:

```
let width:Double = 94.4
let widthLabel = "The width is \(width)"
```

Comment: but can you do it *implicitly* (i.e. without the "`:Double`" declaration)?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but I do know I could do that. What I want to know is why is Integer supported but Double/Float aren't, and what's the difference between String(var) and var.description

Comment: I would imagine that Ints are supported because there is no ambiguity about their String representation, whereas floating point numbers have several representations and many possible precisions.