# Xcode6 Cannot invoke 'subscript' with an argument list of type

Tags: swift, invoke

Cannot understand why xcode tries to invoke a subscript, I do not want it from xcode.

I have a simple structure:

```
struct Point3D
{
    var x: Double = 0.0
    var y: Double = 0.0
    var z: Double = 0.0
    init(x:Double, y:Double, z:Double) {self.x = x; self.y = y; self.z = z}
}
```

However the code under doesn't working, it says: `Cannot invoke 'subscript' with an argument list of type '(x: Double, y: Double, z: Double)'`. But as you can see, I have an init with these types...

```
private func convertFileStringToPoint3D(str:String)->Point3D
{
    let components_file_string_point3d = str.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: " \t"))
    if components_file_string_point3d.count>2 {
        return Point3D(x: Double(components_file_string_point3d[0]), y: Double(components_file_string_point3d[1]), z: Double(components_file_string_point3d[2]))
    } else {
        assertionFailure("Wrong File Structure. Cannot convert string to Point3D.")
    }
}
```

And when I try to use doublevalue of NSString it says that it didn't have a member called doublevalue...

I'm so embaressed :( I just missed with one character doublevalue instead doubleValue... This is duplicate, so delete please, there is no question, ust mistake...

Comment: Your problem isn't because of the init on your Point3D class; it's because Double doesn't have an init that takes a String.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031621/swift-how-to-convert-string-to-double ...

Comment: Convince the typechecker that you're in the right here `let components_file_string_point3d : [NSString]`, then invoke `doubleValue`

Comment: Yeah I've already read it, but NsString.doublevalue says that this member doesn't exist

Comment: Are you using doublevalue or doubleValue? Because it's definitely there on NSString for me. I've run my answer below though a Playground and it works fine...

Comment: Matt, one char and so much words... Thanks)

Answer (score 2):

In the same vain as what Matt Gibson said, `Double(value: String)` does not exist. As of now there is no built in way to convert from `String` to `Double`. `String` to `NSString` to `Double` is the standard workaround.

My version of that looks like this:

```
private func convertFileStringToPoint3D(str:String)->Point3D
{
    let components_file_string_point3d = str.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: " \t"))
    if components_file_string_point3d.count>2 {
        return Point3D(
            x: Double((components_file_string_point3d[0] as NSString).doubleValue),
            y: Double((components_file_string_point3d[1] as NSString).doubleValue),
            z: Double((components_file_string_point3d[2] as NSString).doubleValue)
        )
    } else {
        assertionFailure("Wrong File Structure. Cannot convert string to Point3D.")
    }
}
```

It's all how you want your code to work I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Swift's Double doesn't have an initialiser from String. I'd use NSString's doubleValue:

```
    let components_file_string_point3d:[NSString] = str.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: " \t"))
    if components_file_string_point3d.count>2 {
        return Point3D(x: components_file_string_point3d[0].doubleValue, y: components_file_string_point3d[1].doubleValue, z: components_file_string_point3d[2].doubleValue)
```

Note that I'm explicitly specifying the type of components_file_string_point3d so that it's an array of NSString, not Swift String; that lets you access NSString's doubleValue method easily later.

Comment: `[NSString]` it's extra, it causes error, without it working perfectly

Comment: @OlexiyPyvovarov ? I tested my code in a playground as written above and it works fine. If I remove the explicit [NSString] typing, I get "error: 'String' does not have a member named 'doubleValue'" when I use doubleValue. What version of Xcode are you using? Are you using the beta version of the compiler (6.1) or the release version (6.0.1)? I'm using 6.0.1.