# Converting string to double results in 0 value

Tags: ios, type-conversion, swift2

```
let dicAddress:NSMutableDictionary = ["name": "Aravind kumar",    "address":"54/58 second street","city":"chennai","zipcode":"64102322", "state":"tamil nadu", "landmark":"neaer icicic bank", "latitude":"13.0827", "longitude":"80.2707","username":"aravindann" ]

let latitude = String(dicAddress["latitude"])
let longitude = String(dicAddress["longitude"])
let lat = (latitude as NSString).doubleValue
let lon = (longitude as NSString).doubleValue
```

When I try to convert `string` value to `double` I am getting 0 as result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift - How to convert String to Double](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031621/swift-how-to-convert-string-to-double)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```
let lat = Double(latitude)
```