# Swift 2.1 Binary operator * cannot be applied to two String operands

Tags: swift

I have a calculator, but I can´t resolve this code:

```
@IBAction func calcular(sender: AnyObject) {

    resultado.text = String(format: "", Sliderdosis)

    let peso = pesoLabel.text

    let dosis = dosisLabel.text

    let total = (peso * dosis) * 5 / 250

    /* in this point, the program write:
    Binary operator * cannot be applied to two String operands** */

    resultado.text = total     
}
```

Some body help me please?
I´m a beginner, sorry!

Comment: What language is this? Judging by the error message, I'm guessing swift? Please edit the tags in the question to clarify.

Comment: Hi @ValRas. If the answer below has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 2):

The infix binary operator `*` does not exist for type `String`. You are attempting to multiply `String` objects (that are, inherently, not numerical) hence the error.

I'd suggest you make use of [Leo Dabus excellent `UITextField` extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24115141/swift-converting-string-to-int/34294660#34294660), however, in your case, extending `UILabel` (assuming `pesoLabel` and `dosisLabel` are `UILabel` instances)

```
extension UILabel {
    var stringValue : String { return text                ?? "" }
    var integerValue: Int    { return Int(stringValue)    ?? 0  }
    var doubleValue : Double { return Double(stringValue) ?? 0  }
    var floatValue  : Float  { return Float(stringValue)  ?? 0  }
}
```

Add this to the header of your `.swift` file. Thereafter you can update you button action method according to:

```
@IBAction func calcular(sender: AnyObject) {

    resultado.text = String(format: "", Sliderdosis)

    let peso = pesoLabel.doubleValue
    let dosis = dosisLabel.doubleValue
    let total = (peso * dosis) * 5 / 250

    resultado.text = String(total)   
}
```

Finally note that this subject is well-covered here on SO, so there exists existing threads that can help you convert string to numerical values. E.g.

- [Swift - Converting String to Int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24115141/swift-converting-string-to-int)
- [Swift - How to convert String to Double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031621/swift-how-to-convert-string-to-double/)

Also have a look at the [*Asking* section here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), it contains lots of valuable information of *how to ask*, *when to ask*, and so on.

Comment: @ValRas Happy to help.