# How can I unwrap a optional string to then convert it to data type of Double?

Tags: swift, user-input, option-type

I'm designing an app for the company I work for that uses a basic y=mx+c (or y=mx+b if you're from the US) to take 2 calibrated values and 2 input values to output scale and offset values. The app takes a users input from a total of 4 text fields, and then uses a few formulas to output into a text view. My problem is that the input values need to be 'Doubles' for use in the formulas (Divisor, m_FinalScale, m_FinalOffset) whereas the values that the user inputs are 'Strings?' because they are from a text field. How could I go about unwrapping and converting those optional strings to then use?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Cal1Field.delegate = self
    Cal2Field.delegate = self
    Input1Field.delegate = self
    Input2Field.delegate = self

}

//Actions

@IBAction func CalibrateTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    var Divisor = 0.0, m_FinalScale = 0.0, m_FinalOffset = 0.0

    // this is what the formulas are

    Divisor = Input2Field.text - Input1Field.text
    m_FinalScale = (Cal2Field.text - Cal1Field.text)/Divisor
    m_FinalOffset = Cal1Field.text - (m_FinalScale*Input1Field.text)



}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift - How to convert String to Double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031621/swift-how-to-convert-string-to-double)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flatMap` here:

```
let input1 = input2Field.text.flatMap(Double.init)
let input2 = input2Field.text.flatMap(Double.init)
let cal1 = cal2Field.text.flatMap(Double.init)
let cal2 = cal2Field.text.flatMap(Double.init)
```

If you want to avoid the code duplication, you can add an extension over `UITextField`:

```swift
extension UITextfield {
    var doubleValue: Double? { text.flatMap(Double.init) }
}
```

, which you can later use like this:

```swift
let input1 = input2Field.doubleValue
let input2 = input2Field.doubleValue
let cal1 = cal2Field.text.doubleValue
let cal2 = cal2Field.text.doubleValue
```

A couple of notes here:

1. I renamed the text fields to start with a lowercase letter, to follow the Swift [naming conventions](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#follow-case-conventions).
2. `input1`, `input2`, `cal1`, `cal2` are optionals, it your call what to do if some are nil (e.g. the user entered invalid values).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension

```
extension String {
    var convertItToDouble: Double? {
        return Double(self) 
    }
}
```

then in your method

```
@IBAction func CalibrateTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    var Divisor = 0.0, m_FinalScale = 0.0, m_FinalOffset = 0.0

    // this is what the formulas are

    if let doubleCal1Field = Cal1Field.text?.convertItToDouble,  
       let doubleCal2Field = Cal2Field.text?.convertItToDouble, 
       let doubleInput1Field = Input1Field.text?.convertItToDouble, 
       let doubleInput2Field = Input2Field.text?.convertItToDouble {

       Divisor = doubleInput2Field - doubleInput1Field
       m_FinalScale = (doubleCal2Field - doubleCal1Field)/Divisor
       m_FinalOffset = doubleCal1Field - (m_FinalScale*doubleInput1Field)
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend defaulting optionals to 0 in a helper function like that. That defeats the entire point of optionals

Comment: That's much better, though at that point I would suggest just `Cal1Field.text.map(String.init)`, it's shorter and clearer

Comment: i think instead of `Cal1Field.text.map(String.init)` you want to write `Cal1Field.text.map(Double.init)`

Comment: Ah yes, I meant `Double.init`. What do you mean by "not efficient"?

Comment: Thank you all so so much! Works perfectly and my boss is happy.

Comment: happy coding .. =)